# Using Blender on a windows 10 tablet with no keyboard?

Tags: shortcut

Is there any software (in exception of Tablet Pro, which is quite expensive and overfeatured) to create some virtual buttons or shortcuts on the screen to use blender in non-keyboard mode?

Or maybe some lightweight wireless hardware, like a mini-keyboard with a dozen of keys?

I'd like to use my Surface 2017 for sculpting and drawing, but it is almost unusable without some vital shortcuts.

Comment: Hardware shopping questions are off-topic for this site, I believe. As for a virtual keyboard, there surely are options. Have you considered the one built into Windows?

Comment: @JohnDvorak Yep, that was what i started with, but it has too many keys and you can't keep it on the screen because it takes a half of it. All i need are 4-5 basic shortcuts located somewhere by the left edge, easily accessible

Comment: The viewport in 2.8 offers quite a few icons in the toolbar. Would that suffice for you?

Comment: You could buy a mouse with multiple keys and assign those shortcuts to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies, folks. I decided to stay on TabletPro with the only ArtistPad feature activated. It seems to be a good option despite it's quite complicated customization.